# Unable to confirm a permissions request using Dialogflow and Actions on Google

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@wassimchegham/handling-permissions-with-dialogflow-and-actions-on-google-b08c8f228c00) in order to create an action that will request permission to access a user's location and read back their address; however, I cannot confirm the permissions request when the Assistant makes it.

As soon as I am asked if it is okay to get my address from Google, no matter what response I give the Assistant responds with "Sorry, I didn't catch that" or something similar. I'm stumped as to what I'm doing wrong, and I'm certain I've followed the tutorial to the letter.

I've included my intents, my code that is deployed on Firebase Cloud Functions, and the output I'm getting from the Assistant.

```js
// Dialogflow modified SillyNameMaker example
'use strict';

process.env.DEBUG = 'actions-on-google:*';
const App = require('actions-on-google').DialogflowApp;
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.sillyNameMaker = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const requestPermission = (app) => {
        app.askForPermission('To locate you', app.SupportedPermissions.DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION);
    };

    const userInfo = (app) => {
        if (app.isPermissionGranted()) {
            const address = app.getDeviceLocation().address;
            app.tell(`You are at ${address}`);
        } else {
            app.tell('Sorry, I could not figure out where you are.');
        }
    };

    const app = new App({ request, response });
    const actions = new Map();
    actions.set('request_permission', requestPermission);
    actions.set('user_info', userInfo);
    app.handleRequest(actions);
});
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does your code that asks for permission look like?

Comment: @Prisoner I've editing my question to include my code. The requestPermission function gets run when the request_permission action is fired and makes the permission request. The userInfo function runs when the user_info action is fired, which happens when Actions on Google sends the actions_intent_PERMISSION event as a result of the permissions request.

Comment: And just to be clear, what do you see/year when it asks for the location permission? (A screen shot of the test console would be great.)

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the Assistant output.

Comment: Can you try 
1) changing the case of the response (i.e. from 'Yes' to 'yes', and also try 'sure')
2) changing the surface being used for testing (i.e switch between Speaker devices and mobile devices using the switcher in the top right of the simulator)

Answer (score 0):

You have to answer *twice*!

**"To locate you, I'll just need to get your street address from Google. Is that ok?"**

"Yes"

**"Sorry, I didn't get that."**

"I said yes." / "Yes" / "Sure!" etc.

*The ability to execute intents with permissions enabled is now available to you.*

I assume it is some kind of security check. Because of this design, it means that any `context` objects you depend on after the request must have a minimum `lifespan` of `2` to get through to you. I set them to a very high value, then manually remove them in my callback, in case the permissions operation goes on a lot longer than that (i.e multiple failed validation attempts).